# Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError for assets

Tags: webpack, elixir, phoenix-framework, umbrella

in elixir i try to create project under umbrella with this command

```
mix phx.new my_project --umbrella
```

in apps directory try to install phoenix project with this command

```
mix phx.new phx_project --no-ecto
```

and trye to add assets with new structure under the assets directory and new file with bar.css and use it on front end with :

```
<%= Routes.static_path(@conn, "/ja/bee/foo/bar.css") %>
```

I got nothing found.

but with this

```
<%= Routes.static_path(@conn, "/css/app.css") %>
```

it's ok .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to put my assets (js, css, images) under the `assets` directory but the real place, it is in fact under the `assets/static` directory. Personally I think this is not a good place why? Because in `assets` directory we have directories like css, js directory.

Comment: do you mean `priv/static` ?

Answer (score 1):

In your `endpoint.ex` file, you will have a section that looks something like

```
  plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/", from: :attendance_web, gzip: false,
    only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt)
```

You will need to add the `ja` directory to the list in the `:only` key. Then make sure your `ja` directory is beside your `css` directory.